# AndroidのRealmで "io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Too many open files in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp line 113"のエラーが発生する

Tags: android, realm

Androidで現在地の位置情報を取得し、Realmに保存する処理を書いています。
現在地の情報は`LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates`を利用し、PendingIntentでServiceを呼び出し、そこで位置情報を取得しています。

その`IntentService#onHandleIntent`の中で`Realm.getDefaultInstance()`を何度も呼んでいるとクラッシュしてしまいます。

### Serviceの処理

```
class LocationBackgroundService : IntentService("LocationBackgroundService") {

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        intent ?: return
        if(!intent.extras.containsKey(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED)){
            return
        }

        val l = intent.extras.get(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED) as Location
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction { realm ->
            realm.createObject(PathRealm::class.java).apply {
                date = Date()
                latitude = l.latitude
                longitude = l.longitude
            }
        }
        RxBus.send(LocationUpdateEvent(l))
    }
}
```

### トレース

```
E/UncaughtException: io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Too many open files in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp line 113
    at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.createNativeWithImplicitTransactions(Native Method)
    at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.openSharedGroupOrFail(SharedGroup.java:95)
    at io.realm.internal.SharedGroup.<init>(SharedGroup.java:74)
    at io.realm.internal.SharedGroupManager.<init>(SharedGroupManager.java:49)
    at io.realm.BaseRealm.<init>(BaseRealm.java:81)
    at io.realm.Realm.<init>(Realm.java:140)
    at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:240)
    at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:220)
    at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:126)
    at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:166)
    at jp.shikajiro.hogehoge.services.LocationBackgroundService.onHandleIntent(LocationBackgroundService.kt:29)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction〜`とメソッドチェーンで一気に書いているので、Realmのインスタンスが閉じられて（`close()`）いないのが原因です。

下記のように`Realm.getDefaultInstance()`の戻り値（Realmインスタンス）を戻り値で受けて、Realmを使い終わったら必ず`close()`メソッドを呼ぶようにしてください。

`close()`について詳しくはこちら https://realm.io/jp/docs/java/latest/#realm-3 を参照してください。

```
override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    ...

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    realm.executeTransaction { realm ->
        realm.createObject(PathRealm::class.java).apply {
            date = Date()
            latitude = l.latitude
            longitude = l.longitude
        }
    }

    realm.close() // 使い終わったらclose()を呼ぶ
    ...
}
```

Comment: なぜか executeTransaction で closeもやってくれると思い込みをしていました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: closeを素敵にやりたい場合は `Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { `とすればうまくできました＾＾　（kotlinの話になっていしまっていますが）